# Is there a way to change the text speed?

Tags: pokemon-gates-to-infinity

There is a lot of talking in this game, and while it is cute, I can read a lot faster than the game moves. Is there a way for me to change the text speed to something a little faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to hold down B, to make text transitions slightly faster. Other options are not given. From: [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/683850-pokemon-mystery-dungeon-gates-to-infinity/65877645)